# Expect extra characters after close-quote

Tags: ubuntu, unix, ssh, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm getting an error

```
extra characters after close-quote
    while executing
"spawn ssh-add <(echo -e "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
 Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
 DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,2AB77A7C6E344A120BA00670A3CAB833

 AM57TuHYLo..."
```

When using expect and spawn to add ssh key with passphrase.
This is my script:

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
expect -c "spawn ssh-add <(echo -e \"$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY\\r\"); expect \"Enter passphrase\"; send \"$SSH_PASSPHRASE\\r\"; expect eof;"
```

I also tried many combinations when echoing the ssh private key:

```
echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY"
echo \"$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY\"
echo -e \"$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY\"
echo '$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY'
echo '$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY'
```

Comment: in Gitlab Setting in Secret Variables Make sure variable is available in build; for example is not restricted to protected branch or a certain environment

Comment: No, it is not. I've tried using a ssh private key without passphrase and without using expect, and it's working